# Get download state for FastFollow pack in Unity using Play Asset Delivery

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, assetbundle

There was a need to divide the game into separate parts to deliver content, Google offers PAD, which is a good alternative as a free CDN, everything is cool, but it is not clear how, after starting to download FastFollow content and entering the game, display its progress directly in the game

I have configured all the content to the necessary parts (FastFollow/OnDemand), everything works, everything is loading, but if for **OnDemand** when loading via `PlayAssetDelivery.RetrieveAssetPackAsync()` from the request I can get progress, then for **FastFollow** it is a mystery to me

---

Unity: 2021.3.16f1
PAD Plugin: 1.7.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault, method `PlayAssetDelivery.RetrieveAssetPackAsync("my_fast_follow_bundle_name")` returns  me `PlayAssetBundleRequest` where I can see download status and progress any bundle include fast-follow packs

Answer (score 0):

You can load fast-follow bundle through native UnityEngine method

```
AsyncOperationHandle downloadOperation = UnityEngine.Android.AndroidAssetPacks.DownloadAssetPackAsync(assetPacksForDownloading.ToArray());
```

Then, you can get progress from **downloadAssetPackOperation.progress**